# bottle+uwsgi+nginx got an error when I use python-scapy

Tags: python, bottle

bootle debug said:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bottle.py", line 764, in _handle
        return route.call(**args)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bottle.py", line 1575, in wrapper
        rv = callback(*a, **ka)
    File "/home/tin/sg/main.py", line 30, in login
        user.login(sharer)
    File "/home/tin/sg/User.py", line 60, in login
        User.send_tcp(self.ip, sharer.id, sharer.password)
    File "/home/tin/sg/User.py", line 161, in send_tcp
        send(IP(src=ip, dst='destIP') / TCP(sport=sport, dport=80, seq=0, flags='S'))
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scapy/sendrecv.py", line 251, in send
        __gen_send(conf.L3socket(*args, **kargs), x, inter=inter, loop=loop, count=count,verbose=verbose, realtime=realtime)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scapy/arch/linux.py", line 307, in __init__
        self.ins = socket.socket(socket.AF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.htons(type))
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 187, in __init__
        _sock = _realsocket(family, type, proto)

error: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
```

When I run the app in bottle builtin function `run()` , it works. It **only** report this error when I use the `send()` from python-scapy.
and I have aleady do `chown www-data:www-data` to all myapp files.

How to fix my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a resolution by myself.
I modified the setting in the file `uwsgi.ini`
add the execute permission

```
[uwsgi]
uid = root
gid = root
chmod-socket = 777
```